# How to configure ASMX web service URL from remote source

Tags: c#, web-services, url, configuration, asmx

We are working on a legacy C# enterprise app. Its client uses several web services, whose URLs, among lots of other settings, are read from the local app.config file. We want to migrate these settings into a global DB to simplify their management. However, I can't figure out how (and whether) it is possible to migrate the web service URLs. These are read from the service client code generated by VS and I can't seem to find a way to tell VS to use a different settings provider than the one generated into `Settings.Designer.cs` .

We can overwrite the service facade's `Url` property with the value we want, *after* it is created - this is the solution currently used in several places in the code. However, I wouldn't like to touch every part of our codebase where any of these services is used (now and in the future). Even less would I like to modify generated code.

There has to be a better, cleaner, safer solution - or is there?

Btw our app runs on .NET 2.0 and we won't migrate to newer versions of the platform in the foreseeable future.

Comment: It would appear that you need a [Settings Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.settingsprovider.aspx) which can use a database to store the settings in.

Comment: @John, that's how it looks like indeed. Just how can I tell VS to use my SettingsProvider in the generated web service client code?

Comment: @PéterTörök Perhaps these links help http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20917/Creating-a-Custom-Settings-Provider and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8eyb2ct1.aspx and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/136152/Create-a-Custom-Settings-Provider-to-Share-Setting

Comment: Do you already have a custom `SettingsProvider` class?

Comment: @Yahia, thanks, the links provided some guidance to the right direction (alas, at points unclear and/or incorrect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Refernce.cs` file that is generated by the Visual Studio indicates that the URL of the webservice will be retrieved from the settings:

```
this.Url = global::ConsoleApplication1.Properties.
    Settings.Default.ConsoleApplication1_net_webservicex_www_BarCode;
```

I believe that [John Saunders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76337/john-saunders) gave you a wonderful suggestion in his comment. You need a [`SettingsProvider` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.settingsprovider.aspx) which:

> ...defines the mechanism for storing configuration data used in the
>   application settings architecture. The .NET Framework contains a
>   single default settings provider, LocalFileSettingsProvider, which
>   stores configuration data to the local file system. However, you can
>   create alternate storage mechanisms by deriving from the abstract
>   SettingsProvider class. The provider that a wrapper class uses is
>   determined by decorating the wrapper class with the
>   SettingsProviderAttribute. If this attribute is not provided, the
>   default, LocalFileSettingsProvider, is used.

I don't know how much you have progressed following this approach, but it should go pretty straighforward:

1. Create the `SettingsProvider` class:

   ```
   namespace MySettings.Providers
   {
       Dictionary<string, object> _mySettings;

       class MySettingsProvider : SettingsProvider
       {
           // Implement the constructor, override Name, Initialize, 
           // ApplicationName, SetPropertyValues and GetPropertyValues (see step 3 below)
           // 
           // In the constructor, you probably might want to initialize the _mySettings 
           // dictionary and load the custom configuration into it.
           // Probably you don't want make calls to the database each time
           // you want to read a setting's value
       }
   }
   ```
2. Extend the class definition for the project's `YourProjectName.Properties.Settings` partial class and decorate it with the `SettingsProviderAttribute`:

   ```
   [System.Configuration.SettingsProvider(typeof(MySettings.Providers.MySettingsProvider))]
   internal sealed partial class Settings
   {
       //
   }
   ```
3. In the overridden `GetPropertyValues` method, you have to get the mapped value from the `_mySettings` dictionary:

   ```
   public override SettingsPropertyValueCollection GetPropertyValues(
       SettingsContext context,
       SettingsPropertyCollection collection)
   {
       var spvc = new SettingsPropertyValueCollection();
       foreach (SettingsProperty item in collection)
       {
           var sp = new SettingsProperty(item);
           var spv = new SettingsPropertyValue(item);
           spv.SerializedValue = _mySettings[item.Name];
           spv.PropertyValue = _mySettings[item.Name];
           spvc.Add(spv);
       }
       return spvc;
   }
   ```

As you can see in the code, in order to do that, you need to know the setting name as it was added in the `app.config` and the `Settings.settings` when you have added the reference to the web service (`ConsoleApplication1_net_webservicex_www_BarCode`):

```
<applicationSettings>
    <ConsoleApplication30.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="ConsoleApplication1_net_webservicex_www_BarCode"
            serializeAs="String">
            <value>http://www.webservicex.net/genericbarcode.asmx</value>
        </setting>
    </ConsoleApplication30.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

This is a very simple example, but you might use a more complex object to store the configuration information in conjunction with other properties available in the context such as `item.Attributes` or `context` in order to get the proper configuration value.

Comment: Thanks Alex, this really cleared things up! I was trying and failing the whole day to make my settings provider work, due to the sad fact that the material I found so far was contradicting and/or simply incorrect. Your step 2 above was the key which I haven't found anywhere else. It has earned you the bounty, but I can only award it tomorrow...

Comment: @PéterTörök, I'm glad it helped. Good luck with your implementation!